# Tamir.SharpSsh Redirect Output (Sha1)

Tags: c#, output, console-application

I'm using Tmir.SharpSsh - SshExec method in order to send some commands to remote SSH server.

The problem is that this method or some thread it's created sends output to my console windows ("Sha1").

I want to ask if somebody know I can I disable this prints or redirect it to some temp file.

```
    public static bool OpenConnection (ConnectionInfo info)
    {
        string command = "nslookup " + info.IP + "| grep \"name = \" | awk -F\" = \" '{print $2}' | cut -d\".\" -f-1";
        exec = new SshExec(info.IP, info.UserName,info.Password);

        try
        {

            exec.Connect();
            if (exec.Connected)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connection to {0} is successfully", info.IP);
                info.Hostname=(exec.RunCommand(command)).Trim().ToUpper();//retrive Hostname from the RPA
                return true;
            }

            else
                return false;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return false; 
        }

    }
```

[image: Console Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to disable the line `Console.WriteLine("Sha1");` into the method named `public byte[] doFinal()`, in the file `HMACSHA1.cs`